# @Alternative and Default implementation CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

```
@Inject
Instance<FooInterface> fooInstances;

DefaultImplementation implements FooInterface{}

@Alternative
@Priority(1)
AlternativeImplementation implements FooInterface{}
```

Would like to iterate through and return the fooImplementation requested as parameter, although the Instance only has the AlternativeImplementation and not the DefaultImplementation.

What would be a solution to sort this problem out? I really need both implementations available.

```
public FooInterface getImplementation(String name){
   Iterator<FooInterface> iterator = fooInstances.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          FooInterface fooInterface = iterator.next();
         if (fooInterface .getName().equals(strategyName)) {
              return fooInterface ;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/cdi-and-instance-3-pitfalls-you-need-to-know/). Basicaly it says it is not possible with an alternative. I cannot find anything in the spec regarding this, but it makes some sense to me. If you define an alternative (for the current module) you hide the (other) default implementation(s). I tested it and experienced the same behavior. As a result, using the `Instance` with `@Any` works if you do not have any alternative bean.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `@Any` qualifier is for.  All beans have the `@Any` qualifier unless someone has gone to extraordinary lengths to omit it.

```
@Inject
@Any
Instance<FooInterface> fooInstances;
```

Be aware that you will now have to apply the relevant alternative-and-priority-and-default instance logic yourself.  Chances are you're after something else, but strictly speaking this is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CDI Specification](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#enablement):

> 5.1.2. Enabled and disabled beans
>
> A bean is said to be **enabled** if:
>
> - it is deployed in a bean archive, and
> - it is not a producer method or field of a disabled bean, and
> - it is not specialized by any other enabled bean, as defined in Specialization, and either
> - **it is not an alternative, or it is a selected alternative of at least one bean archive or the application**.
>
> Otherwise, the bean is said to be **disabled**.

In your scenario, `DefaultImplementation` is a disabled bean since an alternative `AlternativeImplementation` bean is selected due to the presence of the `@Priority` annotation.

---

Proceed as following:

1. Remove `@Alternative` annotations from all classes implementing `FooInterface`
2. Introduce a [qualifier](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#qualifiers) to select preferred instance:

   ```
   @Qualifier
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
   public @interface Preferred {
   }
   ```
3. Annotate `DefaultImplementation` with that qualifier

   ```
   @Preferred
   DefaultImplementation implements FooInterface{}
   ```
4. Use the following injection point declaration to get access to all beans implementing the interface:

   ```
   @Inject
   @Any
   Instance<FooInterface> fooInstances;
   ```

   You would need to handle the `@Priority` explicitly in the code though.
5. Use the following injection point declaration to get the preferred bean:

   ```
   @Inject
   @Preferred
   FooInterface preferredFooInstance;
   ```